# Cursor stuck at corner of window

Tags: windows-7, cursor, tablet, trust

Recently I have bought a Trust "Fresco Widescreen Tablet" ( http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=18002 ). At first i had no problems using it, plug and play tablet, it worked nice.

After a clean install of my operating system (Windows 7), I can't get my tablet get to work again :( .

I have tried installing several drivers, but none seemed to work (officially i don't need any drivers, according to the trust website).

I have 2 screens (Benq G2420HD) with an AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series (Catalyst-version 12.10) on a windows 7 operating system.

My PC detects movement on the tablet (tries to move it out of the corner). I can't calibrate my tablet, because i can't get my cursor out of the corner.

My mouse works fine.
Does anyone have any idea why I can't get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. This question is better suited to [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com)